# Rails Setting Null Times on Update

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a Rails 3.2.16 legacy app where I record call information and times on each call `en_route_time` `on_scene_time`, etc all are `datetime` fields.

In my `Call` show view I have an edit times path which redirects to an `edit_times` view via a get request.  This allows you to edit times in case errors were made.

**edit_times in calls_controller.rb**

```
  def edit_times
    @call = Call.find(params[:id])
  end
```

**edit_times.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@call) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :En_Route_Time %>
  <%= f.date_select :en_route_time %>
  <%= f.time_select :en_route_time,
  :combined => true,
  :default => Time.zone.now,
  :include_blank => true,
  :minute_interval => 1,
  :time_separator => "",
  :start_hour => 00,
  :end_hour => 23 %>

  <%= f.label :On_Scene_Time %>
  <%= f.date_select :on_scene_time %>
   <%= f.time_select :on_scene_time,
   :combined => true,
   :default => Time.zone.now,
   :include_blank => true,
   :minute_interval => 1,
   :time_separator => "",
   :start_hour => 00,
   :end_hour => 23 %>

   <%= f.label :To_Hospital_Time %>  
   <%= f.date_select :to_hospital_time %>
    <%= f.time_select :to_hospital_time,
    :combined => true,
    :default => Time.zone.now,
    :include_blank => true,
    :minute_interval => 1,
    :time_separator => "",
    :start_hour => 00,
    :end_hour => 23 %>

  <%= f.label :At_Hospital_Time %>
  <%= f.date_select :at_hospital_time %>
   <%= f.time_select :at_hospital_time,
   :combined => true,
   :default => Time.zone.now,
   :include_blank => true,
   :minute_interval => 1,
   :time_separator => "",
   :start_hour => 00,
   :end_hour => 23 %>

   <%= f.label :In_Service_Time %>
   <%= f.date_select :in_service_time %>
    <%= f.time_select :in_service_time,
    :combined => true,
    :default => Time.zone.now,
    :include_blank => true,
    :minute_interval => 1,
    :time_separator => "",
    :start_hour => 00,
    :end_hour => 23 %>

    <%= f.button :Submit %>
<% end %>
```

This works fine, however when editing times if a time is not populated it will update_attributes with a default time when blank is selected `0:00`.

So I wrote the following private method in `calls_controller' to allow blank times if the`5i`params is blank on the update action and use a`before_filter` to trigger it.

**calls_controller.rb**

```
before_filter :filter_blank_call_times, only: [:update]
 def filter_blank_call_times
    if params[:call]['en_route_time(5i)'].blank?
        params[:call]['en_route_time(1i)'] = ""
        params[:call]['en_route_time(2i)'] = ""
        params[:call]['en_route_time(3i)'] = ""
        params[:call]['en_route_time(4i)'] = ""
        params[:call]['en_route_time(5i)'] = ""
    end
    if params[:call]['on_scene_time(5i)'].blank?
        params[:call]['on_scene_time(1i)'] = ""
        params[:call]['on_scene_time(2i)'] = ""
        params[:call]['on_scene_time(3i)'] = ""
        params[:call]['on_scene_time(4i)'] = ""
        params[:call]['on_scene_time(5i)'] = ""
    end
    if params[:call]['to_hospital_time(5i)'].blank?
        params[:call]['to_hospital_time(1i)'] = ""
        params[:call]['to_hospital_time(2i)'] = ""
        params[:call]['to_hospital_time(3i)'] = ""
        params[:call]['to_hospital_time(4i)'] = ""
        params[:call]['to_hospital_time(5i)'] = ""
    end
    if params[:call]['at_hospital_time(5i)'].blank?
        params[:call]['at_hospital_time(1i)'] = ""
        params[:call]['at_hospital_time(2i)'] = ""
        params[:call]['at_hospital_time(3i)'] = ""
        params[:call]['at_hospital_time(4i)'] = ""
        params[:call]['at_hospital_time(5i)'] = ""
    end
    if params[:call]['in_service_time(5i)'].blank?
        params[:call]['in_service_time(1i)'] = ""
        params[:call]['in_service_time(2i)'] = ""
        params[:call]['in_service_time(3i)'] = ""
        params[:call]['in_service_time(4i)'] = ""
        params[:call]['in_service_time(5i)'] = ""
    end
  end
```

**routes.rb except**

```
  resources :calls do
    member do
      post 'close'
      post 'cancel'
      post 'note'
      get 'opencall'
      get  'new_return'
      get 'duplicate_call'
      get 'edit_times'
      put 'update_billing'
      post 'dispatch_call'
      put 'en_route'
      put 'on_scene'
      put 'to_hospital'
      put 'at_hospital'
      put 'in_service'
    end
    collection do
      get "scheduled"
      get "call_search"
    end
  end
```

This works fine when editing times and allows for a blank time to be entered if the `5i` `datetime` field is blank.

The problem I'm having is when editing/updating a call through the normal edit/update convention, whenever I do edit the call it wipes out whatever times are there.

I'm looking for a way to either write a conditional in the `update` method in `calls_controller.rb` where `filter_blank_call_times` is only called if any of the `5i` keys are blank.  The way it's working right now is that when you edit times it calls the `update` action on the `calls_controller` and sets all of the times to nil.  I need to figure out a way to only perform the `filter_blank_call_times` method when editing times, not when editing/updating a call to prevent call times from being wiped out.

If there is a better way of doing this, such as building another controller for `edit_times` and nesting that resource under calls or somehow doing a post request instead of utilizing the `update` action action on the `calls_controller` I'd love to hear about it.

So in summary, editing times is no problem, but calling this on the update action wipes out the time calls and I need to figure out a way around this.

If my question is not clear or you need more information/code, please let me know.

Here's an except of the params that are passed when calling the `update` action in `calls_controller`

`Started PUT "/calls/125" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-08 06:59:05 -0500
Processing by CallsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"uH+XDJpZQDH4PNAuOOi7dfLVolfRzziMKWc/rSR6UMg=", "call"=>{"caller_name"=>"James Jelinek", "caller_phone"=>"281-444-2222", "caller_address"=>"", "patient_name"=>"Doe, John", "billing_address"=>"", "patient_dob"=>"2001-10-17", "patient_age"=>"12", "patient_sex_id"=>"1", "insurance_id"=>"4", "nature_id"=>"2", "region_id"=>"2", "transfer_from_id"=>"3", "transfer_from_other"=>"", "facility_from_location"=>"", "transfer_to_id"=>"", "transfer_to_other"=>"123 w 8th st Houston, TX 77088", "facility_to_location"=>"ER Room 2", "service_level_id"=>"1", "special_equipment_ids"=>["", "2"], "transfer_date(2i)"=>"10", "transfer_date(3i)"=>"2", "transfer_date(1i)"=>"2014", "transfer_date(5i)"=>"00:00:00", "wait_return"=>"yes", "parent_call_id"=>"124", "traffic_type"=>"Non-Emergency", "unit_ids"=>["", "1"], "call_status"=>"open"}, "button"=>"", "id"=>"125"}`

Comment: Why 5(i) keys can not have 00 instead?

Comment: @Surya Sorry, I'm not sure I'm understanding what you're asking.  If I edit times and the time has not been populated yet, I want it to be a nil value instead of a datetime object that defaults to 0:00

Comment: I didn't understand what you're trying to say either. Can you post the log data of `params` when you post data to create/update method?

Comment: @Surya Sorry for the miscommunication, I updated my question with a sample log of the params hash when the `calls_controller` calls `update`

Comment: See: `"transfer_date(5i)"=>"00:00:00"` in `params` it has 00:00:00 so my question was: Why you need to look for `.blank?` you could simply let be 00, right?

Comment: @Surya `transfer_date` was intentionally set to 00:00:00 on this call.  I'm actually focusing on the other time fields such as `en_route_time`, `on_scene_time`, etc.  `transfer_date` is a non-issue at this time.  I'm looking for `blank?` on the other times and if the params passed are blank, write a nil value to all of the `datetime` fields.  If I don't use this private method, when editing times that have not populated yet, the `edit_times` form will default them to 0:00 where I'd rather have the field be nil.  Sorry if this is confusing.

Comment: `transfer_date` isn't even on the form you've posted in this question.  Is it an item to be avoided when updated fields?  (As in, the form field exists but it's not one to be changed/tampered with?)

Comment: @6ftDan `transfer_date` only gets passed as a param from the main `_form.html.erb` that I use to create or edit calls.  The `edit_times.html.erb` is used strictly for editing these proprietary call times and does not include `transfer_date`

Answer (score 0):

To check the time against all zeros, nil, or empty this regex should work.

```
"00:00:00"::=~(/[1-9]/).nil?
 => true
```

And instead of manually writing everything out you can write code to grab the text before "(5i)" and change all the other values to empty.  The code would look something like this:

```
params["call"].keys.each {|item|
  post_text = "(5i)" # Set the target text we're looking for
  if !!item[post_text] # If target text matches
    if params["call"][item]::=~(/[1-9]/).nil? # Time is all zeros, nil, or empty
      pre_text = item[0...item.index(post_text)] # get the text from before target
      params["call"].keys.select {|i|
        !!i[pre_text] and !i[post_text] #select the OTHER values that match the pre_text
      }.each {|like_item|
        params["call"][like_item] = "" # set all the OTHER values that match the same pre_text to ""
      }
    end
  end
}
```

Note if you want to change the `(5i)` field to blank as well you'd change it to this:

```
params["call"].keys.each {|item|
  post_text = "(5i)" # Set the target text we're looking for
  if !!item[post_text] # If target text matches
    if params["call"][item]::=~(/[1-9]/).nil? # Time is all zeros, nil, or empty
      pre_text = item[0...item.index(post_text)] # get the text from before target
      params["call"].keys.select {|i|
        !!i[pre_text] #select the values that match the pre_text (including post_text)
      }.each {|like_item|
        params["call"][like_item] = "" # set all the values that match the same pre_text to ""
      }
    end
  end
}
```

Either of these get placed inside

```
def filter_blank_call_times
  # CODE HERE
end
```